# Compile error with OpenCV 3.3.0 and xfeatures2d

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv-contrib

I downloaded the latest versions of opencv 3.3.0 and opencv_contrib, did the cmake with CUDA support and the make gives me:

```
....
[ 80%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 80%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_xfeatures2d
[ 80%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/sift.cpp.o
/home/cesar/programas/instaladores/OpenCV/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT_Impl::detectAndCompute(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, cv::OutputArray, bool)’:
/home/cesar/programas/instaladores/OpenCV/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1156:9: error: ‘removeDuplicatedSorted’ is not a member of ‘cv::KeyPointsFilter’
         KeyPointsFilter::removeDuplicatedSorted( keypoints );
         ^
modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/build.make:670: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/sift.cpp.o'
make[2]: *** [modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/sift.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:21949: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/all'
```

I'm lost here. I tried updating my cmake from 3.5 to 3.8 and the building stops at the same point.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got downmodded, yet have not received any feedback.

Your question, I believe, doesn't really belong on stackoverflow. `opencv_contrib` Is explicitly unstable. The API's for the contained modules are under development and are subject to change at any point in time. Build errors may well arise when building it, too.

I think you'd be better off trying to file a bug report with the module's developers.

Answer (score 0):

removeDuplicatedSorted is just added to opencv master branch 3 days ago and is not back ported to 3.3.0 yet. However sift is updated to it. opencv_contrib tend to sync with master branch. it doesn't have a matching version branch/tag